# ROR How to remember user without registration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies

I have ror app where i can poll. How to remember user without registration? That he could not vote many times for the same answer.
What should I use? I need to create a new model for users? Maybe use some gems?

Comment: This is extremely broad... But, you can get started on user sessions and registration with this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch?view=asciicast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every visitor to your Rails website will be given a `session`, you can just store some state in there like: `session[:seen] = true` and in subsequent requests you can check for the existence of that session variable.

[See here for more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) and especially note that a user can always thwart this effort by clearing their cookies (which is why it would be better to use registration).

Comment: Just save the session using the database or server cache instead of cookies. Database will remember the user as long as he is using the same machine with the same IP, server cache will stay on as long as it has enough memory to store all users. When memory starts to run thin, it will start forgetting users, starting with the ones that haven't accessed for the longest time.

Comment: Forgot to mention that these 2 other ways are to prevent user being able to vote again by clearing cookies

Comment: I'm not sure where you got your information @RodrigoCastro, but it's simply not true. Switching the storage of the session data over to database or memory doesn't change how the visitor is tracked - which is always with a cookie.